# Filter numpy array of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, filter, scikit-learn, stockquotes

`Scikit-learn` library have a brilliant example of data clustering - [stock market structure](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html). It works fine within US stocks. But when one adds tickers from other markets, `numpy`'s error appear that arrays shoud have the same size - this is true, for example, german stocks have different trading calendar.

Ok, after quotes download I add preparation of shared dates:

```py
quotes = [quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl(symbol, d1, d2, asobject=True)
          for symbol in symbols]


def intersect(list_1, list_2):
    return list(set(list_1) & set(list_2))

dates_all = quotes[0].date
for q in quotes:
    dates_symbol = q.date
    dates_all = intersect(dates_all, dates_symbol)
```

Then I'm stuck with filtering numpy array of tuples. Here's some tries:

```py
# for index, q in enumerate(quotes):
#     filtered = [i for i in q if i.date in dates_all]

#     quotes[index] = np.rec.array(filtered, dtype=q.dtype)
#     quotes[index] = np.asanyarray(filtered, dtype=q.dtype)
#
#     quotes[index] = np.where(a.date in dates_all for a in q)
#
#     quotes[index] = np.where(q[0].date in dates_all)
```

How to apply filter to numpy array or how to truly convert list of records (after filter) back to `numpy`'s `recarray`?

quotes[0].dtype:

```
'(numpy.record, [('date', 'O'), ('year', '<i2'), ('month', 'i1'), ('day', 'i1'), ('d', '<f8'), ('open', '<f8'), ('close', '<f8'), ('high', '<f8'), ('low', '<f8'), ('volume', '<f8'), ('aclose', '<f8')])'
```

quotes[0].shape:

```
<class 'tuple'>: (261,)
```

Comment: By array of tuples I suspect you mean a `structured array` (or `recarray`).  If so we'd like to know the `shape` and `dtype` of the array.

Comment: Thanks for note. Added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `quotes` is a list of recarrays, and in `date_all` you collect the intersection of all values in the `date` field.

I can recreate one such array with:

```
In [286]: dt=np.dtype([('date', 'O'), ('year', '<i2'), ('month', 'i1'), ('day', 
     ...:
     ...: ), ('low', '<f8'), ('volume', '<f8'), ('aclose', '<f8')])
In [287]: 
In [287]: arr=np.ones((2,), dtype=dt)  # 2 element structured array
In [288]: arr
Out[288]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.),
       (1, 1, 1, 1,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.)], 
      dtype=[('date', 'O'), ('year', '<i2'), ('month', 'i1'), ('day', 'i1'), ... ('aclose', '<f8')])
In [289]: type(arr[0])
Out[289]: numpy.void
```

turn that into a recarray (I dont' use those as much as plain structured arrays):

```
In [291]: np.rec.array(arr)
Out[291]: 
rec.array([(1, 1, 1, 1,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.),
 (1, 1, 1, 1,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.)], 
          dtype=[('date', 'O'), ('year', '<i2'), ('month', 'i1'), ('day', 'i1'), .... ('aclose', '<f8')])
```

`dtype` of the recarray displays slightly different:

```
In [292]: _.dtype
Out[292]: dtype((numpy.record, [('date', 'O'), ('year', '<i2'), ('month', 'i1'), ....('aclose', '<f8')]))
In [293]: __.date
Out[293]: array([1, 1], dtype=object)
```

In any case the `date` field is an array of objects, possibly of `datetime`?

`q` is one of these arrays; `i` is an element, and `i.date` is the date field.

```
 [i for i in q if i.date in dates_all]
```

So `filtered` is list of recarray elements.  `np.stack` does a better job of reassembling them into an array (that works with the recarray too).

```
np.stack([i for i in arr if i['date'] in alist])
```

Or you could collect the indices of the matching records, and index the quote array

```
In [319]: [i for i,v in enumerate(arr) if v['date'] in alist]
Out[319]: [0, 1]
In [320]: arr[_]
```

or pull out the date field first:

```
In [321]: [i for i,v in enumerate(arr['date']) if v in alist]
Out[321]: [0, 1]
```

`in1d` might also work to search

```
In [322]: np.in1d(arr['date'],alist)
Out[322]: array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [323]: np.where(np.in1d(arr['date'],alist))
Out[323]: (array([0, 1], dtype=int32),)
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response and suck NumPy tricks: `i['date']`, `in1d` an others!